# Displaying data from mysql into android studio using JSON

Tags: php, android, json, android-studio, xampp

i want to display data from mysql into android using textview,, but when im running the app, its goes force stop itself,
can someone help me how to fix it,,
any idea would be nice

dbconfig.php

```html
<?php

//This script is designed by Android-Examples.com
//Define your host here.
$servername = "localhost";
//Define your database username here.
$username = "root";
//Define your database password here.
$password = "";
//Define your database name here.
$dbname = "u727224026_demo";

?>
```

send-data.php

```html
<?php
include 'dbconfig.php';


// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "SELECT * FROM TextViewTable";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

    // output data of each row
    while($row[] = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

       $json = json_encode($row);


    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
echo $json;
$conn->close();
?>
```

MainActivity.java

```js
package flix.yudi.kuesioner2;

import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    TextView textview;
    JSONObject json = null;
    String str = "";
    HttpResponse response;
    Context context;
    ProgressBar progressbar;
    Button button;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        progressbar = (ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);
        textview = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);

        progressbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                progressbar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                new GetTextViewData(context).execute();

            }
        });
    }


    private class GetTextViewData extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>
    {
        public Context context;


        public GetTextViewData(Context context)
        {
            this.context = context;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute()
        {
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0)
        {

            HttpClient myClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost myConnection = new HttpPost("192.168.1.139/a_test/send-data.php");

            try {
                response = myClient.execute(myConnection);
                str = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity(), "UTF-8");

            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


            try{
                JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(str);
                json = jArray.getJSONObject(0);



            } catch ( JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            catch (Exception e)
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result)
        {
            try {
                textview.setText(json.getString("ServerData"));

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            //Hiding progress bar after done loading TextView.
            progressbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        }
    }


}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.jsonparsingfromurltextview_android_examples.com.MainActivity" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="TextView Static Text Before Load"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:gravity="center"/>

<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="17dp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="150dp"
    android:text="Click Here to Load TextView data dynamically from MySQL Database Online Using JSON Parsing" />
```

logcat error notif

```
10-03 08:35:35.486 1754-2070/flix.yudi.kuesioner2 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
                                                                Process: flix.yudi.kuesioner2, PID: 1754
                                                                java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
                                                                    at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300)
                                                                    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
                                                                    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
                                                                    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
                                                                    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
                                                                    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
                                                                    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
                                                                    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
                                                                 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Target host must not be null, or set in parameters. scheme=null, host=null, path=192.168.1.139/a_test/send-data.php
                                                                    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.determineRoute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:591)
                                                                    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:293)
                                                                    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
                                                                    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
                                                                    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
                                                                    at flix.yudi.kuesioner2.MainActivity$GetTextViewData.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:84)
                                                                    at flix.yudi.kuesioner2.MainActivity$GetTextViewData.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:60)
                                                                    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
                                                                    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
                                                                    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231) 
                                                                    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112) 
                                                                    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587) 
                                                                    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

i tried to find how to fix it, but still nothing,
please help me,

[ADDITIONAL INFO RESPONSE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KSa2P.png)

Comment: Try to download Postman, and then try to send a post request to your url.

Do you have a response ?

Comment: thanks for your suggest,
ill try to find how to use it,
cause i dunno that,,

Comment: Should be easy, it's good and intuitive

Comment: i has edit my post about Screenshot of response from another app like postman, now what should i do for the next step sir? do you have an idea?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding some scheme like `http` or `https` to the `URL`:

```
http://192.168.1.139/a_test/send-data.php
```

Comment: i had added http or https to the URL,,
but its still force close itself, do you have another idea sir?

Answer (score 0):

First of all try ur service call in postman ... check whether you r getting right response from 192.168.1.139/a_test/send-data.php

follow [her](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman/fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop?hl=en) to get postman plugin

Check give code below

```
 private String makeRESTService(String methodNameWithUrl) throws JSONException {
        final String KEY_USER_NAME = "username";
        final String KEY_PASSWORD = "password";
        System.out.println("url" + methodNameWithUrl);
        String jsonResult = null;
        String jsonObj = null;

        //create a json string
        JSONObject parent = new JSONObject();
        parent.put(KEY_USER_NAME, "manu");
        parent.put(KEY_PASSWORD, "1234");
        Log.e("To json", jsonObj);

        URL url = null;

        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
        try {
            url = new URL("your url"); //place your url
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            urlConnection.setReadTimeout(10000);
            urlConnection.setConnectTimeout(15000);

            urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
            OutputStream os = urlConnection.getOutputStream();

            BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(
                    new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));
            writer.write(jsonObj);
            writer.flush();
            writer.close();
            os.close();

            urlConnection.connect();
            InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());
            jsonResult = inputStreamToString(in)
                    .toString();
            Log.e("jsonResult", jsonResult);

            //   readStream(in);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            urlConnection.disconnect();
        }
        return jsonResult;

    }


    private StringBuilder inputStreamToString(InputStream is) {
        String rLine = "";
        StringBuilder answer = new StringBuilder();
        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
        BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(isr);
        try {
            while ((rLine = rd.readLine()) != null) {
                answer.append(rLine);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return answer;
    }
```

Comment: thank you for the code and your reference,,
ill try it,
do you have another app for firef*x sir? 
but where should i put your code above?
should i create new java class?

Comment: inside doinBackground of AsyncTask

Comment: i already attach a Screenshot respone from server sir,, what do you think? did i doing something wrong?